# How to pass PATH parameter from a script to a batch file?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have this Python script I have been working on and I cannot seem to fix this problem when calling a batch file from a separate directory, here is my script for reference

```py
def makeFolder(folderName=""):
    try:
        os.mkdir(path + "/" + folderName)
    except OSError:
        print("Error creating folder.")


def p(string=""):
    os.system('cls')
    print(string)


path = os.getcwd().replace("/python", "")
name = input("What would you like the client to be called? ") + " 1.8.8"
mcp = "http://www.modcoderpack.com/files/mcp918.zip"
optifine = "http://download2265.mediafire.com/bdd5w08f1zcg/e878f5djmyuvnxm/Optifine.zip"
updatedDecompileFile = "https://pastebin.com/raw/Mwt03EEs"


def setup():
    makeFolder(name)

    p("Created folder '%s'." % name)

    zipPath = name + "/src.zip"

    p("Downloading MCP 1.8.8 from %s" % mcp)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(mcp, zipPath)
    p("Finished Downloading MCP 1.8.8")

    p("Unzipping MCP 1.8.8")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(path + "/" + name)
    os.remove(zipPath)
    p("Unzipped MCP 1.8.8")

    mcpPath = path + "/" + name + "/"

    for file_name in listdir(mcpPath):
        if file_name.endswith(('.bat', '.sh')):
            os.remove(mcpPath + file_name)

    os.remove(mcpPath + "CHANGELOG")
    os.remove(mcpPath + "LICENSE.txt")

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(updatedDecompileFile, name + "/decompile.bat")

... this is where I would need to run the batch file ...

setup()
```

Currently I have the user go into the specified directory and run the batch file inside, due to an issue where running the batch file prompts that it cannot find the path. Here is the batch file for reference:

```bsh
@echo off
runtime\bin\python\python_mcp runtime\decompile.py
pause
```

The Python file this batch script calls requires the path to be `syspath\project\Client`.

However when calling the batch file programmatically from the Python script located in the directory `syspath\project` it throws an error. However when manually executing the file located in `syspath\project\Client` it works perfectly as intended.

I figured the answer would lie in the path parameter passed from the batch file shown above to the Python script it executes. So me being new to Python, my only work around I could think of was to "spoof" the path so it told the Python file it was executed in `syspath\project\Client` rather than `syspath\project`.

**If you need any further information please let me know, without making my post too lengthy I tried to get my question across.**

Comment: To start with you need to protect the space character in your path, i.e. `"runtime\bin\python\python_mcp runtime\decompile.py"`. Also, unless you can guarantee, that the end user has added the location to their python executable, `python.exe` to their `%PATH%` and/or that `.py` extension files are automatically run using it, you may need to prepend that line with `python.exe` or its full or relative path. I also note that you're not specifying locations, so you may want to change your directory inside the batch file, to ensure that those are correct for your circumstances.

Comment: Before running the batch file from the script, change the cwd (current working directory) to the one it is in.

Comment: @martineau oh my.. why did i not think of that.. this makes me feel so stupid but thank you for the answer none the less. I was so wrapped up in the python portion of the project i completely forgot the answer could have just as easily been in the batch script..

Comment: Christian: No worries, sometimes it takes another pair of eyes to see what's conspicuous — been there, done that.

Comment: Note that the environment variable `PATH` is not used to find commands that have a slash in their names, so setting it wouldn’t help anyway.